# How to push UIViewController into UINavigationController from seperate UIView of different UIViewController which uses this view

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` (`AbcViewController`) with `NavigationController`. `AbcViewController` uses UIView (`AbcView`) as its view. `AbcView` has a `UITableView`. I have set this `TableView`'s datasource in `AbcViewController` and delegate in its `SuperView` i.e. `AbcView`. How will I push another `UIViewController` (`XyzViewcontroller`) into navigationController when I select a row in this table because it gives

> "error: request for member 'navigationController' in something not a structure or union"

when I do this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:xyzViewcontroller animated:TRUE];
```

I also did this:

```
AbcViewController *parentVC;
[parentVC.navigationController pushViewController:xyzViewcontroller animated:TRUE];
```

Though it builds successfully, `XyzViewcontroller`'s view does not appear. It does not push `XyzViewcontroller`'s view onto navigationController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make a delegate on `AbcView` so that we can refer back to the view's viewController which in this case is `AbcViewController`. We can set delegate as:

```
@interface AbcView : UIView

{ 
    id delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

Then in `AbcViewController`, set the view's delegate like this:

```
[abcView setDelegate:self];
```

Now in table method using our delegate from within AbcView as:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [delegate pushOtherView];

}
```

it will call `- (void)pushOtherView` method in `AbcViewController` whose definition is:

```
- (void)pushOtherView 
{   
    XyzViewcontroller * xyzViewcontroller = [[[XyzViewcontroller alloc] init] autorelease];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:xyzViewcontroller animated:YES];   
}
```

But before using this method, it should be mentioned in protocols otherwise it will show

> Warniing:
>
> -pushOtherView' not found in protocol(s).